# problem with glreadPixels on iphone

Tags: iphone, c++, opengl-es

I have no problem drawing a texture to the screen but I cant get the right pixels when printing them from memory. I have a 4x4 png image with 4 black pixels and I am trying to print them. This is what I do:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textureId);

const int size = m_width * m_height * 4;
GLubyte pixels[size];

glReadPixels(0, 0, m_width, m_height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
if(glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR)
    assert(false && "opengl error");


for(int index = 0; index < size; index+=4)
{
    cout << "red " << (unsigned)pixels[index+0] << endl;
    cout << "green " << (unsigned)pixels[index+1] << endl;
    cout << "blue " << (unsigned)pixels[index+2] << endl;
}
```

But I get all random values and not the one I expect. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glReadPixels reads from framebuffers, not textures. To retrieve the contents of a texture object use glGetTexImage: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetTexImage.xml

Comment: but does glGetTexImage exists in opengl es?

Comment: @Merni right, there's no glGetTexImage in OpenGL-ES. Well there's little need for it anyway, as since textures are created from data the program supplies, one can expect that the program can access that data anytime. If the textures are created by rendering and glCopyTexImage one can use glReadPixels at the same point one uses glCopyTexImage.

Comment: @Merni: How about this workaround: Create a framebuffer object and bind the textue in question as the color buffer. Then select that framebuffer for reading and use glReadPixels on it.

Comment: @datenwolf what if you want to retrieve pixels from a texture that has been modified / filtered?

Comment: @PsychoDad: On OpenGL-ES: Same method as what I wrote to Merni: Bind the texture, draw a quad, read back results with glReadPixels. On regular OpenGL, glGetTexImage, but normally you modify textures by having them attached to a FBO as color attachment anyway, so you can just do the glReadPixels then.